# Dapper SimpleCRUD custom handlers ignored

Tags: dapper, custom-type, dapper-simplecrud

If I execute queries with [SimpleCRUD](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD) i.e., `connection.GetList<_type>();` , then my custom type handlers are never executed. If I execute the same query directly with `connection.Query<_type>(queryString)`, then my custom handlers get called without any issue. Am I doing something wrong? I can see that SimpleCrud also just calls `Dapper.Query<T>`. I can't seem to find the issue on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually SimpleCRUD will ignore all types that is not `TypeExtension.IsSimpleType()`

This happens inside `GetScaffoldableProperties`
Modifying a few lines of code fixes the issue (i.e., removing the check for `IsSimpleType()`)

OR 
One could simply set `[Editable(true)]` flag on the complex type field.